# Getting Jquery script to call action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2, post

Good Morning Stack OverFlow enthusiasts.  I have been having an issue that I am attempting to narrow down, and I could use the help of the good people at stack overflow...  For some reason, the action controller that I attempt to call from a view never executes... I have breakpoints set and everything and it just never seems to get called...

```
    $(function () {
$("#DemoGraphSubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = [];
    $.getJSON("/PatientACO.aspx/SearchByDemographic", null, function (data) {
        data = $.map(data, function (item, a) {
            return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("#PatientListToAdd").html(data.join(""));
    });
});
```

});

I checked to make sure that the url is correct... PatientACOController is my controller and SearchByDemographic is my action method...  DemoGraphSubmit is the button in my view that submits...  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Best place to start is the _Console_ of either Firefox (with Firebug) or Chrome to see exactly which URL JavaScript is calling and the contents of the response.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using IE to develop this thing... I do prefer the easy of use of firefox

Comment: I don't know anything about asp action controllers, but is your URL bound to an HTTP GET? jQuery's getJSON will only work with GET, not POST

Comment: @DmainEvent fair enough, but that doesn't stop you viewing the site in a browser with decent development tools in order to track down the problem :-)

Comment: @tinyd my action controller is peppered by an httpPost attribute...  But In my return value I JsonRequestBehaviorallowGet... That might be causing some issues.  Trying to use the native tools in IE and fiddler to see what I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the default routing in MVC the URL should be `/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic`.

The `.aspx` part shouldn't exist

Comment: Thats true... I did change that, but I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Have a look in Firebug (or similar) and let us know what's going on in there.

Comment: Currently having issues with my internet connection on my work machine.  This might take a while.

Comment: OK.  Everytime I click on the button, an httpRequest for my local host at /PatientACO/SearchByDemographic is issued.  It says 443 bytes where sent, 9,860 were recieved...

Comment: Ok, I am getting a 500 internal Server Error...  The Parameter Dictionary contains a null entry for a parameter I call my method with... How do you pass parameters using .getJson?

Comment: The second parameter to getJSON (where you have null) is for parameters

Comment: Ok,  I need to switch my method to post, and I need to pass in a parameter plus all of the formData as a paramter to my action method... Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You can set up your action method for a POST by setting a [HttpPost] attribute above the controller method

Comment: The getJson method in jQuery doesn't seem to have a property for type. The ajax() however does and so you may be best using that if you want to go with a POST.

Comment: dumb question... one of the parameters needs to be passed to the controller... It can't possibly be know at compile time... how do I pass that .net variable to the javascript?  I was thinking about doing...
<script javascript...>
var PopID = <% PopID %>  Does that make any sense?
Also, I have to pass the formCollection to my action Method in my controller aswell... So I am serializing it like so...
var form = $("#DemoGraphID").serialize();  Do you think that could work?  I will ask this as a new question...

Comment: You can either write out the value directly in your javascript code or add it to a variable outside of your current JS code that you have access to. `var myValue = <%= MyServerObject.SomeProperty %>`